# addClass on condition

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li class="action">item</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#list li:last").addClass("active");
```

This almost works, but the "action" item takes the "active" class when its present which I don't want. How do I rewrite the above jQuery so it always ignores the `li.action` and assigns "active" class to the last `li` before it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:not()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector) selector. E.g.

```
$("#list li:last:not(.action)").addClass("active");
```